# Amazon Opsworks Loading Old Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

I have a two EC2 instance in Application Layer of my Amazon Opsworks work stack. A month ago, I have upgraded my infrastructural from medium to large EC2 instances. I have test the application and it was working fine. I am using Custom Chef JSON to generate a redis.yml file which look like this:

```
production:
  host: 54.0.0.*
  port: 6379
```

When ever I deploy my code to Application server I provide Custom Chef JSON to update redis.yml file.

Last week I found this error **'Timed out connecting to Redis on 52.1.214.123:6379'** in server logs of my application. When I opened redis.yml file it contains old server IP which I have closed during infrastructure upgrate. When I redeploy code as I did after infrastructure and provide IP in Custom Chef JSON, redis.yml got updated and error was gone.

In Opsworks stack setting I still have old params which will be execute if I add a new EC2 instance in my stack.

Now my question is that how can I debug this issue which cause the EC2 instance to use stack's Custom Chef JSON?

I already have run the following command but have found any deployment traces other then my self.

```
sudo opsworks-agent-cli show_log [activity] [date]
```

Thanks